# Groupby and flatten lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following form:

```
import pandas as pd
p = pd.DataFrame({"int" : [1,     1,     1,     1,     2,      2],
                  "cod" : [[1,1], [2,2], [1,2], [3,9], [2,2], [2,2]]})
```

I want to group by `int`, which gives me a bunch of lists. I then want to flatten these lists, so I ultimately end up with a dataframe that has this form:

```
p = pd.DataFrame({"int" :  [1,                2],
                  "cod" : [[1,1,2,2,1,2,3,9], [2,2,2,2]]})
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
p.groupby("int", as_index=False)["cod"]
```

I'm stuck at how to flatten once I have grouped by `int`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `sum`:

```
df = p.groupby("int", as_index=False)["cod"].sum()
```

Or `list comprehension`:

```
df = p.groupby("int")["cod"].apply(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]).reset_index()
```

---

```
df = p.groupby("int")["cod"].apply(lambda x: np.concatenate(x.values).tolist()).reset_index()
```

For performance if large list should be fastest:

```
from itertools import chain

df = p.groupby("int")["cod"].apply(lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x))).reset_index()
```

---

Check more information about [flattening lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914).

---

```
print (df)
   int                       cod
0    1  [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 9]
1    2              [2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: @jezrael Which is fastest?

Comment: @N08 - I hope last one, but the best test with real data. `sum` I think is not very fast.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the `sum`. (+1)

Comment: @meW - Thank you.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for the links to the monoids and the list flattening (+1)