# Appending lists of words or characters from all rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to append lists present in different rows in a dataframe without using a 'for' loop ?

I am able to achieve that by using 'for' loop, but I want to achieve this in a much more efficient way, probably without using 'for' loop

```
d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'col2': [['a'],['a','b','c'],['d'],['e'],['a','e','d']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
word_list = []
for i in df['col2']:
  word_list = word_list + i
```

I want to get an output list like this: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'd']

Comment: For all possible answers have a look on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54089037/10734525 by jezrael. The notion of that question is little different but the approach is what you can learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it is with `panda`'s `sum` function:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'col2': [['a'],['a','b','c'],['d'],['e'],['a','e','d']]}
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

In [2]: df['col2'].sum()
Out[2]: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'd']
```

However, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is much faster:

```
In [3]: import itertools
   ...: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['col2']))
Out[3]: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'd']

In [4]: %timeit df['col2'].sum()
92.7 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df['col2']))
20.4 µs ± 2.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

In my testing, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` can be up to 30x faster for larger dataframes (~1000 rows). Another option is

```
import functools
import operator

functools.reduce(operator.iadd, df['col2'], [])
```

which is pretty much equally as fast as `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. I made a graph for all of the answers that were posted:

[image]

(The x-axis is the length of the dataframe)

As you can see, everything using `sum` or `functools.reduce` with `operators.add` is unusable, with `np.concat` being slightly better. However, the three winners by far are `itertools.chain`, `itertool.chain.from_iterable`, and `functools.reduce` with `operators.iadd`. They take almost no time. Here is the code used to produce the plot:

```
import functools
import itertools
import operator
import random
import string

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot # see https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot for this awesome library


def gen_data(n):
    return pd.DataFrame(data={0: [
        [random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(random.randint(10, 20))]
        for _ in range(n)
    ]})

def pd_sum(df):
    return df[0].sum()

def np_sum(df):
    return np.sum(df[0].values)

def np_concat(df):
    return np.concatenate(df[0]).tolist()

def functools_reduce_add(df):
    return functools.reduce(operator.add, df[0].values)

def functools_reduce_iadd(df):
    return functools.reduce(operator.iadd, df[0], [])

def itertools_chain(df):
    return list(itertools.chain(*(df[0])))

def itertools_chain_from_iterable(df):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df[0]))

perfplot.show(
    setup=gen_data,
    kernels=[
        pd_sum,
        np_sum,
        np_concat,
        functools_reduce_add,
        functools_reduce_iadd,
        itertools_chain,
        itertools_chain_from_iterable
    ],
    n_range=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 4000, 5000],
    equality_check=None
)
```

Comment: `sum` has O(n^2) complexity so that 30x will become much higher for larger dataframes. It is practically not usable for anything that has 100k+ rows.

Answer (score 4):

Can't find a dupe, sum of lists will return a combined list

```
df.col2.sum()

['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'd']
```

Or use Numpy

```
np.sum(df.col2.values)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or use `numpy.concatenate`:

```
print(np.concatenate(df['col2']).tolist())
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'd']
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. I get `[['a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d'], ['e'], ['a', 'e', 'd']]`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, another way(Just FYI):

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,df.col2.values)
```

or:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
reduce(operator.add,df.col2.values)

#['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'd']
```

Comment: great going genius :)

Comment: Thank you @meW. :) glad you liked it.

Comment: Sorry to one-up you again, but this is 30-40x slower than my `functools.reduce` solution above for a dataframe with 1000 rows.

Comment: @anky_91 I tested both the first and second, I was talking about the second.

Comment: @Tomothy32 we both seem to be thinking on the same lines, again , didnt realise when you added the `functools.reduce` part since I was in typing mode then. :)

Comment: Our answers were somewhat similar, if you are interested I added a full performance comparison for all of the answers.

Comment: @Tomothy32 : Nice one. :) Cant upvote again, already did so. :D