# How to groupby a column in dataframe which contains a column containing list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to group my dataframe by values in one of the columns, 'category'. Although, one of the other columns 'prob' contains a list of tuples on each row. When I try to group-by 'category', the 'prob' column disappears.

My current df:

```
 category          other:          prob:
   one              val         [(hi, hello), (jimbob, joe)]
   one              val2        [(this, not), (is, work), (now, any)]
   two              val2        [(bob, jones), (work, here)]
   three            val3        [(milk, coffee), (tea, bread)]
   two              val3        [(money, here), (job, money)]
```

Expected output:

```
 category:           other:         prob:
   one             val, val2     [(hi, hello), (jimbob, joe), (this, not), (is, work), (now, any)]
   two             val2, val3    [(bob, jones), (work, here), (money, here), (job, money)]
   three           val3          [(money, here), (job, money)]
```

What is the best way to do this? Apologies if I have mis-phrased this question please let me know if you have any questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can aggregate data by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with `join` for string column and flatten data for tuples - added 3 solutions, `sum` use only if small data and performance is not important:

```
import functools
import operator

from  itertools import chain

f = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
#faster alternative
#f = lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x))
#faster alternative2
#f = lambda x: functools.reduce(operator.iadd, x, [])
#slow alternative
#f = lambda x: x.sum()
df = df.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg({'other':', '.join, 'prob':f})

print (df)
  category       other                                               prob
0      one   val, val2  [(hi, hello), (jimbob, joe), (this, not), (is,...
1    three        val3                     [(milk, coffee), (tea, bread)]
2      two  val2, val3  [(bob, jones), (work, here), (money, here), (j...
```

**Performance**:

[image: pic]

**Code for testing**:

```
np.random.seed(2019)

import perfplot
import functools
import operator

from  itertools import chain


default_value = 10

def iadd(df1):
    f = lambda x: functools.reduce(operator.iadd, x, [])
    d = {'other':', '.join, 'prob':f}
    return df1.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg(d)

def listcomp(df1):
    f = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
    d = {'other':', '.join, 'prob':f}
    return df1.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg(d)

def from_iterable(df1):
    f = lambda x: list(chain.from_iterable(x))
    d = {'other':', '.join, 'prob':f}
    return df1.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg(d)

def sum_series(df1):
    f = lambda x: x.sum()
    d = {'other':', '.join, 'prob':f}
    return df1.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg(d)

def sum_groupby_cat(df1):
    d = {'other':lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', '), 'prob':'sum'}
    return df1.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg(d)

def sum_groupby_join(df1):
    d = {'other': ', '.join, 'prob': 'sum'}
    return df1.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg(d)


def make_df(n):
    a = np.random.randint(0, n / 10, n)
    b = np.random.choice(list('abcdef'), len(a))
    c = [tuple(np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_letters), 2)) for _ in a]
    df = pd.DataFrame({"category":a, "other":b, "prob":c})
    df1 = df.groupby(['category','other'])['prob'].apply(list).reset_index()
    return df1

perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[iadd, listcomp, from_iterable, sum_series,sum_groupby_cat,sum_groupby_join],
    n_range=[10**k for k in range(1, 8)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

Comment: @anky_91 - Just added :)

Answer (score 2):

You could `GroupBy` the `category` column and aggregate with the following functions:

```
df.groupby('category', as_index=False).agg({'other':lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', '),
                                            'prob':'sum'})
```

Which for the first rows gives:

```
   category   other                             prob
0      one  val, val2  [(hi, hello), (jimbob, joe), (this, not), (is,...
1      two      val2                       [(bob, jones), (work, here)]
```

Comment: try `operator.idd` under `reduce()` think will be faster. :)

Comment: Yeah you mean for the strings? yes another option I guess. Would be interesting to see the timingss @anky_91

Comment: yes, for flattening lists which has the tuples, i have tested, after itertools, `operator.iadd()` is almost as fast. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54103720/appending-lists-of-words-or-characters-from-all-rows-in-a-dataframe/54103814#54103814)

Comment: Also added performance graph to my answer, `sum` is slowiest.

Comment: Nice to see the timings @jezrael. Yes indeed it looks like `sum` is slower than using a list comp. It seems as they all scale similarly though. thx for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)+[agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df.groupby('category').agg({'other': ', '.join, 'prob': 'sum'})
```

Comment: You need to provide a description of how your proposed solution meets the needs of the original poster. This helps both the original poster and anyone else who finds this question.